# Find all analytic functions on the interior of the rectangle satisfying these equalities

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: find all functions $f$ analytic in the interior of the rectangle with vertices $1+i,1-i/2,-1/2-i/2,-1/2+i$ such that $f(z+1)=f(z)$ and $f(z+i)=1+f(z)$ whenever these quantities are defined.

My attempt: we can pretty easily extend $f$ to an entire function such that $f(z+1)=f(z)$, $f(z+i)=f(z)+1$. Then the function $z\mapsto e^{2\pi if(z)}$ is entire and doubly periodic, hence a constant. So such $f$ doesn't exist. But the problem clearly said to find all such functions...

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why do you say can be easily extended to an entire function ? Can't there be singularities at the boundaries of the rectangle ?

Comment: I don't understand why there should be singularities on the boundary. We extend $f$ to the subset $\{z\in\mathbb{C}|\,\text{Im }z\in(-1/2,1/2]\}$ by $f(z)=f(z-n)$, where $n$ is the unique integer such that $\text{Re }z-n\in(-1/2,1/2]$. Then we extend $f$ to the entire complex plane by $f(z)=f(z-mi)+m$, where $m$ is the unique integer such that $\text{Im }z-m\in(-1/2,1/2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argumentation is correct: There is no such function $f$.

Instead of $e^{2\pi if(z)}$ you could also – after extending $f$ to an entire function – consider the derivative $f'(z)$ which is entire and doubly periodic, so that $f$ is of the form $f(z) = az+b$. This also leads to a contradiction to the given identities.

Comment: Thank you! The phrasing of the question got me totally confused.